# How to use environment variables in remix run deployed on cloudflare pages

Tags: cloudflare, remix.run

How is it possible to use environment variables in remix when deploying to cloudflare pages? The documentation gives some examples for different hosting providers, but not for cloudflare pages. After assuming, that `dotenv` is the way to go, I get the error `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` after running `npm run dev` which executes `"dev:remix": "node -r dotenv/config node_modules/.bin/remix watch"`.

How is it possible to use environment variables with remix in a cloudflare pages context?

Comment: I ended up replacing the script with `node -r dotenv/config node_modules/@remix-run/dev/cli.js`. However, that is for development. You may need to check the `@remix-run` directory under `node_modules` to find the right script.

Answer (score 1):

For local development, create the file `.dev.vars` in the root directory and add your environment variables:

```
MY_SUPER_SECRET_TOKEN=12345
```

*Best to also `.gitignore` this file too so you don't accidentally commit something for hackers to find.*

On Cloudflare, set the same environment variables in the page's control panel.

Then, in your route's `LoaderFunction` or `ActionFunction`, access the environment variables through the context:

```
export const action: ActionFunction = async ({ request, context }) => {
  console.log(context.MY_SUPER_SECRET_TOKEN)
}
```